# How to format a time interval concisely as ISO 8601 start/end in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601

I want to represent a time interval as start/end but also while taking advantage of the abbreviations that ISO 8601 seems to allow: for interval end fields that are the same as in the starting point. For example, the interval starting right now and lasting a week would be 2016-06-08T12:27Z/15T12:27 (note the omission of a second "2016-06-").

To ward of potential XY-problem second-guessing: I *don't* want this interval represented as 2016-06-08T12:27Z/P1W, even if it is shorter. I *do* want the end time represented directly, but abbreviated to the extent possible.

I don't think DatePeriod does what I want - does it? It seems to either do half the job (start and end independently, with no possibility for abbreviation) or the wrong job (returning a duration, not an end time).

Comment: PHP let's you have total control over date formatting. Just specify your desired format when outputting the date. There's not special that needs to be done.

Comment: @JohnConde I can't specify a static format because I don't know a priori which fields will be identical and ripe for omission. IOW I can't know statically what my "desired format" (in terms of strftime-like functions) is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your problem. But what about short record of  period:

Make string `2016-06-08T12:27Z/2016-06-15T12:27`

and by simple regex reduce it:

```
^(.+)\b(.+)\/\1(.+)  to  \1\2/\3  =>  2016-06-08T12:27Z/15T12:27
```

[demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/oG2mK4/1)

**UPDATE**

Common result after testing

```
^(.*)(?:\b|T)(.*Z)\/\1(.+)Z$
```

[demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/oG2mK4/7)

Comment: It's hackish, but the kind of hackish I tend to like ("less is more" philosophy). Let me introspect a bit to determine the price of my soul before I accept this. Never thought of regexing it! One thought: 2016-06-08T12:27Z/2016-07-15T12:27Z fails. Probably not hard to fix though, with a judicious \b added somewhere.

Comment: Fails ? Are you about tailing Z ? Just add Z to the end of the pattern

Comment: Your regex-replace changes 2016-06-08T12:27Z/2016-07-15T12:27Z into 2016-06-08T12:27Z/7-15T12:27Z. It should be 2016-06-08T12:27Z/07-15T12:27Z (zero-padded month). October-December would be wrong in substance, not just in letter. But no biggie; (.+)\b(.+)\/\1(.+) seems to do the trick.

Comment: @BerndJendrissek This seems to fail if the start and end are in different years? https://www.regex101.com/r/oG2mK4/4

Comment: I've add start of line

Comment: Added lookbehind to treat 'T' like a boundary, anchor at both ^ and $, and always expect Z. https://www.regex101.com/r/oG2mK4/6 Any more bugs left?

Comment: for `2016-06-08T12:27Z/2016-06-08T13:28Z` what sould be ? Not `2016-06-08T12:27Z/13:28` ?

Comment: @splash58 Yes, I believe 2016-06-08T12:27Z/2016-06-08T13:28Z should become 2016-06-08T12:27Z/13:28 Note that my link to version 6 has an test string for 3016, not 2016.